# Why is sampling from a gamma distribution so much slower than from a normal distribution?

Tags: performance, random

I'm doing some simulations for my thesis where we test out different models. One of the parameters which we vary is the distribution. The code runs slower than I would like.

After a lot of profiling, I think I've narrowed it down to the huge difference in compute time between sampling from the gamma distribution as compared with the normal. This can be seen from the relevant part of the following flame graph (output by VTune).

[image]

The simulation spends 212s of CPU time on gamma vs 14s for the normal. Should I be surprised by this? I don't want to waste a ton of time going over the source of the RNG library I'm using if this isn't an implementation-specific issue. I'm by no means an expert in random number generation, but I do recall from my rudimentary study of the topic a long time ago that there are some very efficient algorithms which are specific to normal sampling (Box-Muller and such). Could this really account for such a large differential?

**Edit:** I'm using the C++ RNG library [TRNG](https://www.numbercrunch.de/trng/) because of its parallel capability and integration within the R ecosystem. The main loop is in Fortran so some boilerplate is needed to interface:

```cpp
#include <trng/yarn2.hpp>
#include <trng/normal_dist.hpp>
#include <trng/gamma_dist.hpp>

using namespace trng;

extern "C" {

void* init_rng_f(int seed) {

  void* res = (void*) new yarn2((unsigned long) seed);

  return(res);

}

void* init_lrng_f(void* rng, int thread_total, int thread_num) {

  yarn2* ptr = static_cast<yarn2*>(rng);

  yarn2* lrng = new yarn2(*ptr);

  (*lrng).split((unsigned int) thread_total, (unsigned int) thread_num);

  void* res = (void*) &lrng;

  return(res);
}

double rnorm_par(void* lrng, double mean, double sd) {
  normal_dist<> dist(mean, sd);
  yarn2* ptr = static_cast<yarn2*>(lrng);

  double res = dist(*ptr);
  return(res);
}

double rgamma_par(void* lrng, double shape, double scale) {
  gamma_dist<> dist(shape, scale);
  yarn2* ptr = static_cast<yarn2*>(lrng);
  double res = dist(*ptr);
  return(res);
}

}
```

In Fortran:

```
use iso_c_binding

implicit none

interface

      function rnorm_par(lrng, mean, sd) result(res) bind(c)
         import
         type(c_ptr), value :: lrng
         real(c_double), value :: mean
         real(c_double), value :: sd
         real(c_double) :: res
      end function rnorm_par

      function rgamma_par(lrng, shape, scale) result(res) bind(c)
         import
         type(c_ptr), value :: lrng
         real(c_double), value :: shape
         real(c_double), value :: scale
         real(c_double) :: res
      end function rgamma_par

      function init_rng_f(seed) result(res) bind(c)
         import
         integer(c_int), value :: seed
         type(c_ptr) :: res
      end function init_rng_f

      function init_lrng_f(rng, thread_total, thread_num) result(res) bind(c)
         import
         type(c_ptr), value :: rng
         integer(c_int), value :: thread_total
         integer(c_int), value :: thread_num
         type(c_ptr) :: res
      end function init_lrng_f

end interface
```

Very simply put, this is what the main loop does:

```
rng = init_rng_f(42)

allocate(lrngs(n_threads))

do i = 1, n_threads
   lrngs(i) = init_lrng_f(rng, n_threads, i - 1)
end do

do i_sim = 1, n_sim
  ! Some setup code calculating parameters.
  if (dist == GAMMA) then
    rgamma_par(lrng, shape, scale)
  else
    rnorm_par(lrng, mean, sd)
  end if
  ! Some code to store results.
end do
```

Comment: You've pretty much answered your question. Look at what you have to calculate to get a value from the gamma function. I think you need to invert the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: You forgot to share the code involved such that others could run this on their own

Comment: @matt I'm looking for confirmation from experts. You're right about the inversion, but that's the case for the normal as well. Of course, I can imagine that the gamma one is computationally more complex, but could that really account for such a large difference?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm afraid it's too large to post here.

Comment: The gamma function is very general, maybe specific parameters have quick solutions so it would depend on the specific gamma function. Why would it be too large to create a test case? All you're doing is benchmarking the generation of random numbers. That way people can see the library your using and how your generating the numbers.

Comment: @matt Oh sure, I can add a test case! And yeah, the code calls it with many different parameters.

Comment: That might make it a better question, but as you mentioned the normal function has quick techniques for calculating. Generate 2 random numbers, get two random numbers from the normal distribution. The gamma function, I think you could take a look at the source from the library you're using and see pretty quickly it is much more complicated with non-trivial calculations.

Comment: @matt You're right, I was just not expecting that this would cause a 15x slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

You will find many alternative algorithms for generating gammas starting on page 405 of [Chapter 9](http://luc.devroye.org/chapter_nine.pdf) in Luc Devroye's text [Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation](http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html). The best contenders for consistent speed use a combination of composition (break the distribution down into subcomponent distributions using conditional probability) and acceptance/rejection (try something random, and if it fails keep trying until you get a success). The composition phase involves evaluating transcendental functions, which are computationally expensive. One component of the acceptance/rejection scheme is to generate normals, and may be required many times. So yes, generating gammas with generic parameterizations will definitely be slower than generating normals. There are specific parameterizations which can be substantially faster than generic ones though.

Not knowing which particular algorithm your library is using, I can't be any more specific than that.

Comment: After looking through the source, it seems that they're using inverse transform sampling, and only distinguishing the special case of the exponential distribution (which doesn't arise in my use-case). Could this cause that a severe a bottleneck?

Comment: "Could this cause that a severe a bottleneck?" I don't see why not. The composition+accept/reject algorithms exist because direct inversion was considered too slow back when Devroye wrote his text. For instance, [Marsaglia's polar method was created because acceptance/rejection was both faster (on average) and more numerically stable than direct calculation of sines and cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box–Muller_transform#Contrasting_the_two_forms).  If Devroye says that the composition+accept/reject approach yielded more consistent speed than alternatives, I tend tot believe him.